# How can I correct my script to toggle a given cell from TRUE > FALSE > TRUE?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When I run my script, I want it to write TRUE and then FALSE in cell A1. It doesn't toggle when I run it. I want it to cycle through in one pass. Thanks!

```
function myFunction() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sh0 = sheet.getSheets()[0];
 var sh1 = sheet.getSheets()[1];
 var testRange = sh0.getRange("A1");
 testRange.setValue("TRUE");
Utilities.sleep(10000);
 testRange.setValue("FALSE");


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` in between.

CHanges to the sheet are buffered which is why you're not seeing the changes immediately. Calling `flush` forces any pending changes to be written to the sheet immediately.